# what element choose to show images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

i want to get urls of images ( a variable number ) and show them in my app with a next and back button.
Should i make an UIImageView and make 2 button next and back ? or there is an element for that ?
thanx

Answer (score 3):

`UIImageView` and buttons is the way to go. Also you can check out [Three20](http://three20.info/) for premade components.